# Arduino: Sending data from arduino to Google App Engine datastore with login enabled

Tags: python, google-app-engine, arduino, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently involved in an Arduino and Google App Engine (GAE) project. I am designing an ambient sensor system, consisting of a temperature sensor, light sensor and motion sensor. I am also developing a webapp using Google App Engine. Users can use this webapp to view their ambient status through the cloud, in an IoT fashion.

I have an Arduino Uno and an Arduino Ethernet Shield. I have been successfully able to send sensor data to GAE datastore, but only when login is DISABLED in the webapp.

When I enable user login for the webapp, the Arduino data DOES NOT get sent to the google datastore.

My question: How do I get the Arduino to send data to the Google Datastore, with a username identity appended to it?

Ideal scenario: users can append their google account email address to the arduino code, and data that is sent from the arduino to the datastore is visible by this Google account only, when the user logs into the app with their Google account.

Right now, only the URL of my webapp is provided in the arduino code. How and where do I indicate a particular Google account identity? In my arduino code, this is the only line which informs the arduino of my webapp. What other lines of code should I include to achieve my desired results?

```
//Server to connect to
char serverName[] = "http://ambienators-nus.appspot.com";
```

Here is the partial arduino code.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below
byte mac[] = {  0x00, 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDE, 0x02 };

//Server to connect to
char serverName[] = "http://ambienators-nus.appspot.com";

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
EthernetClient client;
 
void setup()
{
  analogReference(INTERNAL);
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // start the Ethernet connection:
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0)
  {
    while(true);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);

}
 
void postData()
{
  String temperature = String((int)(temp+0.5));
  String lightStr = String((int)(light));
  String move = String(movement);
  String moves1 = String(moves);
  String data = String("temp="+ temperature+"&movement="+move+"&moves="+moves1+"&light="+lightStr);
  while(!client.connected())
  {
    Serial.println("Connecting to client: ");
    client.connect(serverName, 80);
  }
  client.println("POST /arduino_post HTTP/1.1");
  client.println("Host: ambienators-nus.appspot.com");
  client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
  client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(data.length());
  client.println("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  client.println("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
  client.println();
  client.print(data);
  Serial.print(data);
  client.println();
  Serial.println();
  char c;
  while(client.available())
  {
    c = client.read();
  }
  client.stop();
}
```

You may view the webapp here: http://ambienators-nus.appspot.com

You can find the rest of the webapp code in this github repo: https://github.com/taniach/ambienators-nus

Answer (score 0):

Didn't go through all the code, and personally I think that a good practice is to post just significant parts of it for letting people get more easily where the problem could be.

As for your question, why together with sensor data not sending also a string that identify that specific arduino board (this could be maybe the username of the person associated with the board? This way is the webapp could know what board/user is sending each chunck of data and store the values in the correspondent database entity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my original post.

I do understand that conceptially, the username of the person associated with the board can be used. However, coding wise, how do I implement this into the code of the arduino?

Comment: Why not adding just some univocal id for each board like
'const int boardId = 0' for the first board, 'const int boardId = 1' for the second board and so on...